Karate Driver Not Able To Capture Cross Domain Cookies
I am trying to capture the cross domain and 3rd party cookies for a sample website as shown in the attached snippet.
I have a requirement in my project to capture the cross domain and 3rd party cookies for a given website.
For example, if I take the below website, I am not able to capture the cross domain and 3rd party cookies.
Is there any way to capture cross domain cookies using karate or any workaround that can be used within karate feature file?
Feature: Karate UI Testing - CIBC Cookie Test

  Background:
    * configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', executable: 'lib/chromedriver.exe' }

  @CookieSelectionTestCaseCIBC
  Scenario: Cookie selection
    # Open the web page
    Given driver 'https://www.cibc.com/'
    And delay(3000)
    # Capture the cookies
    And def initialCookies = driver.cookies
    * print 'Initial Cookies Size:', karate.sizeOf(initialCookies)
        * print 'Initial Cookies:', initialCookies
    * screenshot()

I am expecting the cross domain and 3rd party cookies to be printed using karate

Karate simply delegates to the underlying driver call to get all cookies.
The only workaround I can think of is see if cookies can be grabbed via JS (which may be unlikely because of security considerations). Or just make a "plain vanilla API call" using Karate's core, and look at responseCookies.
